Missing user fields using tweepy for streaming Twitter data collection
I'm trying to collect data from twitter using its tweepy API. I got the information on the tweets but I didn't get the data on the user even though I included that in the filter. I should point out that I'm using the pro subscription for the twitter API V2 (does it allow me to get the tweets and the information on the author of the tweets?).
here is the code I tried. I expected to have a JSON file containing each tweet and its information per line including the information on the author of the tweet. but I got a JSON file containing only the information on the content of the tweet (this is exactly the fields that are filtered in tweets_fied).
Although I didn't get any errors compiling this code the user field containing subfields: "id","name","username","created_at","description","entities","location","pinned_tweet_id","profile_image_url","protected","public_metrics","url","verifed","withheld" are missed.
here is an example of the JSON file obtained,
{"data": {"article": {}, "attachments": {}, "author_id": "1223367650040078336", "context_annotations": [{"domain": {"id": "6", "name": "Sports Event"}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "11", "name": "Sport", "description": "Types of sports, like soccer and basketball"}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "29", "name": "Events [Entity Service]", "description": "Real world events. "}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "131", "name": "Unified Twitter Taxonomy", "description": "A taxonomy of user interests. "}, "entity": {"id": "1237760060828213249", "name": "Olympics"}}, {"domain": {"id": "6", "name": "Sports Event"}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "11", "name": "Sport", "description": "Types of sports, like soccer and basketball"}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "29", "name": "Events [Entity Service]", "description": "Real world events. "}, "entity": {"id": "1667298425749028864", "name": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics", "description": "Paris 2024 Summer Olympics "}}, {"domain": {"id": "131", "name": "Unified Twitter Taxonomy", "description": "A taxonomy of user interests. "}, "entity": {"id": "1237760060828213249", "name": "Olympics"}}], "conversation_id": "1818294242621493608", "created_at": "2024-07-30T14:35:04.000Z", "edit_controls": {"edits_remaining": 5, "is_edit_eligible": true, "editable_until": "2024-07-30T15:35:04.000Z"}, "edit_history_tweet_ids": ["1818294242621493608"], "entities": {"annotations": [{"start": 15, "end": 27, "probability": 0.9759, "type": "Place", "normalized_text": "Latinoam\u00e9rica"}, {"start": 66, "end": 74, "probability": 0.9628, "type": "Place", "normalized_text": "Guatemala"}], "mentions": [{"start": 50, "end": 60, "username": "Paris2024", "id": "951849552"}, {"start": 77, "end": 92, "username": "COGuatemalteco", "id": "177994528"}]}, "geo": {}, "id": "1818294242621493608", "lang": "es", "possibly_sensitive": false, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 0, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0, "bookmark_count": 0, "impression_count": 0}, "reply_settings": "everyone", "text": "Tercer pa\u00eds de Latinoam\u00e9rica en tener medallas en @Paris2024 Viva Guatemala! @COGuatemalteco"}, "matching_rules": [{"id": "1818294136333623297", "tag": ""}]}

import tweepy
import json
from datetime import datetime

class TwitterCollector:
    def __init__(self, bearer_token, tracked_terms, tweet_limit, languages_filter=None, locations_filter=None):
        self.bearer_token = bearer_token
        self.tracked_terms = tracked_terms
        self.tweet_limit = tweet_limit
        self.languages_filter = languages_filter
        self.locations_filter = locations_filter
        self.tweet_count = 0
        self.file_path = "./tweets.json"

    def save_tweet(self, tweet_data):
        with open(self.file_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(tweet_data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            file.write('\n')

    def setup_rules(self):
        rules = []
        lang_filter = ""
        if self.languages_filter:
            lang_filter = " (" + " OR ".join(f"lang:{lang}" for lang in self.languages_filter) + ")"

        for term in self.tracked_terms:
            rule = f'"{term}"{lang_filter}'
            rules.append(rule)

        return rules

    def manage_rules(self, stream):
        existing_rules = stream.get_rules().data
        if existing_rules is not None:
            rule_ids = [rule.id for rule in existing_rules]
            stream.delete_rules(rule_ids)

        new_rules = self.setup_rules()
        for rule in new_rules:
            stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule(value=rule))

    def start_stream(self):
        stream = TwitterStream(bearer_token=self.bearer_token, collector=self)
        self.manage_rules(stream)

        stream.filter(
            tweet_fields=["attachments","author_id","context_annotations","conversation_id","created_at","edit_controls","entities","geo","id","in_reply_to_user_id", "lang","possibly_sensitive","reply_settings","source","text","withheld"],
            user_fields=["id","name","username","created_at","description","entities","location","pinned_tweet_id","profile_image_url","protected","public_metrics","url","verified","withheld"]
        )

class TwitterStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def __init__(self, bearer_token, collector):
        super().__init__(bearer_token)
        self.collector = collector

    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        self.collector.save_tweet(data)
        self.collector.tweet_count += 1
        if self.collector.tweet_count >= self.collector.tweet_limit:
            print("Tweet limit reached. Stopping the stream.")
            self.disconnect()
        return True

    def on_connection_error(self):
        self.disconnect()
        print("Connection error. Stream stopped.")

# My main
bearer_token = "MY_BEARER_TOKEN"
tracked_terms = ["JO", "Olympic", "#Olympic"]
tweet_limit = 100

collector = TwitterCollector(bearer_token, tracked_terms, tweet_limit)
collector.start_stream()

